# How to drop a column named 'column'?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I need to delete a column named "column" form a table but the standard:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN 'column';
```

returns:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''column'' at line 1
```

I am thinking "column" is reserved word and shouldn't be used. But how do I get around to deleting it ?

Comment: You would want to use a backtick ` to get around the reserved words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct to conclude that "column" is a keyword. Fortunately, you can escape the name so that, keyword or not, it is accepted:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN `column`;
```

Notice the backticks around the column name. This is always the safest way to qualify MySQL object names (for example, did you realize it is possible to use a space in a column name? Not that I encourage this; but it is possible).

If you're curious to look at more craziness, take a look at my post [`;`.`*`.`.` is a valid column name](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/is-a-valid-column-name), which discusses the over-flexibility in object names in MySQL.